# Phonegap/Cordova 2.3.0 iOS Whitelist Ignored

Tags: ios, cordova

I have recently upgraded my phonegap iOS application to 2.3.0. This release converted my Cordova.plist file into a config.xml file as expected, but since the upgrade my application can no longer load resources from external URLs (images etc). I have the following delcaration in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Has anyone come across this issue since the upgrade?

Comment: I think question is not complete. "I have the following delcaration in my config.xml: " are you missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitelist is now specified like so:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

An important thing to note is that if you are using storyboards, you must override `initWithCoder` to call `[super init]` in order to make Cordova load settings from `config.xml`.

The loading is done in `[CDVViewController loadSettings]`. Try breakpointing there and if it is not being called then something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and I am running in storyboards.

Add this to your MainViewController or your controller : CDVViewController

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self = [self init];
    }
    return self;
}
```